# Не поддерживается скролл на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, css

На мобильных устройствах [тут](http://bambizova.posh.pro/index/produkcziya/svezheobzharennaya-arabika/jemen-mokka-sanani.html) и подобных не срабатывает скролл пальцем.

Если проводить пальцем по картинке, то страничка вниз не скроллится.
Если немного сбоку, где я оставил поля, то все работает.

Использовал [этот](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) плагин. Как пофиксить?

[image: изображение]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Событие которое навешано на картинку блокирует скроллинг, либо отключайте его (плагин) при мобильном разрешении, либо просто скрывайте картинку с событием и показывайте обычную (без него), вариантов много, "костылей" ещё больше :)

---

При загрузке получаем ширину экрана `$(window).width()` и при условии что она выше чем мобильная (какая там вам надо) вешаем плагин на картинку.

Comment: Решение с windows.width хорошее можно отключить работу плагина на моб устройствах, но как сохранить возможность по прикосновению на мелкую картинку заменять большую это вот вторая проблема вылезла.

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной для этого пишеться меленький скрипт, который при клике по маленькой картинке, заменяет `src` в главной на новый, который храниться в `data-big-image` (путь к большому изображению) изображения по котором кликнули - как вариант (этот скрипт соответственно должен подключаеться только в мобильной версии)

Comment: Да, благодарю за наводку.. сейчас наверное так и поступлю.

Answer (score 2):

Решение оказалось следующим:

```
<script>
    if($(window).width() > 769) {
        $("#zoom").elevateZoom({gallery:'gall', zoomType:"lens", containLensZoom:true, borderSize:"2", zoomWindowHeight:"100%"});
    } else {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#gall a').click(function() {
                var srcImage = $('#gall a').children().eq($(this).index()).attr('src');
                $('#zoom').attr('src', srcImage);
                return false; //отмена перехода по ссылке
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

спасибо Vlad Vlad за наводку.